# (OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. Windows apache

Tags: windows, apache, amazon-web-services, configuration

When trying to execute httpd.exe on my windows server, I get this error:

> (OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address (myIpAddress):80
>
> AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
>
> AH00015: Unable to open logs

This only happens when in the httpd.conf I set:

> Listening (myIPAddress):80

but the I don't get this error when it's set to:

> Listening 80

Comment: Why are you using your ip address on the `Listen` parameter. `Listen 80` or `Listen 0.0.0.0:80` and possibly `Listen [::0]:80` for IPV6 as well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Confirm if some other process is already listening to Port 80.

```
netstat -aon | findstr :80
```

Since it is windows server there are chances to have IIS running by default.

You will have to stop the website binded with port 80 from IIS Manager and then run httpd.exe again.

Comment: Production server : Currently the 80 listening by IP. so the site running fine but getting error. what could I do? using WAMP

Answer (score 3):

> (OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443 (OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0: 443 AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down

I got this error.
I have installed VMWare software on my PC.
I start a CMD with administrative rights.
In that CMD I execute a powershell command
After powershell started in CMD I execute:

```
Get-Process vmwa* | kill
```

I got a message back

> Confirm
>   Are you sure you want to perform the Stop-Process operation on the following
>   item: vmware-hostd(2164)?
>   [Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help
>   (default is "Y"):

Then I used `A` option and start xampp and Apache without problems.

p.s. I'm writing this if anyone has the same problem and have installed VMWare on their PC-s

Answer (score 0):

Please check if **port no : 80** is already occupy by **Wampapache** service or **World Wide Web service**.

**netstat -aon | findstr :80**

And stop the service which occupy port no 80 & then try to install the new Apache.

Answer (score 0):

I only stopped Skype! this worked...no changes were required to do in Apache config file. Skype is somehow affecting the Apache on port 80
https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=767
Thanks