# Managing multiple sites on XAMPP

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, virtualhost, multiple-sites

I have multiple sites deployed on `xampp`. For now, all of the sites are using one port i.e. `80`. For this reason, whenever I am logged into one of the sites, I am automatically logged out from the other and vice versa. I have looked at this article to [How to run multiple websites on XAMPP on Windows](https://www.wpwhitesecurity.com/multiple-websites-xampp/). And tried to follow it but I am unable to do the needful.

I have added one more port to listen

```
Listen 80 
Listen 8080
```

In my `httpd-vhosts.conf` I have done the following

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
<VirtualHost *:8000>
DocumentRoot "F:\xampp\htdocs\mdc"
ServerName localhost:8080
<\VirtualHost>
```

After doing this I have turned off my xampp and then tried to restart `apache` and `mysql`. But apache is not starting

[image]

My URL is `http://localhost:8080/mdc/backend/web`

**Note:** Without doing any virtual host setting the above URL is accessible on both `80` and `8080` ports

**Update 1**

Herer is my [httpd.conf](https://newtextdocument.com/304786713b) file

Comment: Could you please go into the bin folder and start Apache using `httpd.exe -k start` command and let me know the result.Also share `httpd.exe -t` command output.

Comment: @Pandurang I can't find `bin` folder

Comment: Where I can find it?

Comment: @Pandurang tried this `F:\xampp\apache\bin>httpd.exe -k start
[Thu Jul 16 11:58:24.052631 2020] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 13876:tid 540] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : AH00436: No installed service named "Apache2.4".`

Comment: @Pandurang `httpd.exe -t` gives me `F:\xampp\apache\bin>httpd.exe -t
Syntax OK`

Comment: Start Apache using `httpd.exe -f Abosulate path of httpd.conf` file. Mostly available in `F:\xampp\apache\conf ` folder.

Comment: @Pandurang I am getting this `F:\xampp\apache\bin>httpd.exe -f F:\xampp\apache\conf
httpd.exe: Could not open configuration file F:/xampp/apache/conf: Access is denied.`

Comment: command should be `httpd.exe -f F:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`. Also please check if httpd.conf file available or not at F:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf location.

Comment: @Pandurang after running the command `F:\xampp\apache\bin>httpd.exe -f F:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf
(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs`

Comment: Share your httpd.conf file in question.Also check any other httpd process running or not? If yes then stop httpd process then start using provided command.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51828763/os-10048only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocol-network-address-port

Comment: @Pandurang I have attached my `http.conf` file in `Update 1` please see it

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3660066/4229270. Look like the same issue as you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a fix for your issue, Here i will explain how i manage multiple websites on xampp.

First i assumes that your using `windows`

i always use the same port with different server names.

on : `E:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` (In my case i installed xampp on E drive)
i added this code

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "e:/xampp/htdocs/mysite1"
      ServerName mysite1.flames.com
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "e:/xampp/htdocs/mysite2"
      ServerName mysite2.flames-team.com
    </VirtualHost>
```

And on ( `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`) my windows host file i added this lines

```
127.0.0.1 mysite1.flames.com
127.0.0.1 mysite2.flames-team.com
```

With this approach you can access the site with a clean readable URLs

In this case if you want to see the first site just enter this URL `mysite1.flames.com` on browser.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Write the closing tag `</VirtualHost>` instead of `<\VirtualHost>` in the file `httpd-vhosts.conf`. I did it and it worked for me.