# Running locust with multiple users logging in

Tags: python, locust

This is my code
i did it for logging in with blaze demo
it is a locust file
tried to see for errors like this but no luck
so see if you can help

```
from locust import HttpUser,TaskSet,task,between
import logging,sys
User = [ 
    ("looperotest1@gmail.com", "Loopero@1234"),
    ("looperotest2@gmail.com", "Loopero@1234"),
    ("looperotest3@gmail.com", "Loopero@1234"),
    ("looperotest4@gmail.com", "Loopero@1234"),
    ("looperotest5@gmail.com", "Loopero@1234")
]

class UserBehaviour(TaskSet):
    def on_start(self):
        self.userName="Not_exist"
        self.password="Not_exist"
        if len(User) >0:
            self.userName, self.password = User.pop()

            
    @task(1)
    def login_post(self):
        self.client.post("/login",data={"userName": self.User,"password": self.password})





class User(HttpUser):
    tasks= [UserBehaviour]
    wait_time = between(5, 10)
    host="http://blazedemo.com"
```

it shows this error

C:\testing>locust -f login_blaze.py
[2020-10-28 12:53:30,135] DESKTOP-YAJAT/INFO/locust.main: Starting web interface at http://0.0.0.0:8089 (accepting connections from all network interfaces)
[2020-10-28 12:53:30,157] DESKTOP-YAJAT/INFO/locust.main: Starting Locust 1.3.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "src\gevent\greenlet.py", line 854, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet.run
File "c:\users\yajat\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\locust\web.py", line 391, in start_server
self.server.serve_forever()
File "c:\users\yajat\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\gevent\baseserver.py", line 398, in serve_forever
self.start()
File "c:\users\yajat\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\gevent\baseserver.py", line 336, in start
self.init_socket()
File "c:\users\yajat\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\gevent\pywsgi.py", line 1500, in init_socket
StreamServer.init_socket(self)
File "c:\users\yajat\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\gevent\server.py", line 180, in init_socket
self.socket = self.get_listener(self.address, self.backlog, self.family)
File "c:\users\yajat\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\gevent\server.py", line 192, in get_listener
return _tcp_listener(address, backlog=backlog, reuse_addr=cls.reuse_addr, family=family)
File "c:\users\yajat\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\gevent\server.py", line 288, in _tcp_listener
sock.bind(address)
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted: ('', 8089)
2020-10-28T07:23:30Z <Greenlet at 0x1e3faa4c7b0: <bound method WebUI.start_server of <locust.web.WebUI object at 0x000001E3FAAA57C0>>> failed with OSError

### [2020-10-28 12:53:30,217] DESKTOP-YAJAT/CRITICAL/locust.web: Unhandled exception in greenlet: <Greenlet at 0x1e3faa4c7b0: <bound method WebUI.start_server of <locust.web.WebUI object at 0x000001E3FAAA57C0>>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "src\gevent\greenlet.py", line 854, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet.run
File "c:\users\yajat\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\locust\web.py", line 391, in start_server
self.server.serve_forever()
File "c:\users\yajat\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\gevent\baseserver.py", line 398, in serve_forever
self.start()
File "c:\users\yajat\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\gevent\baseserver.py", line 336, in start
self.init_socket()
File "c:\users\yajat\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\gevent\pywsgi.py", line 1500, in init_socket
StreamServer.init_socket(self)
File "c:\users\yajat\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\gevent\server.py", line 180, in init_socket
self.socket = self.get_listener(self.address, self.backlog, self.family)
File "c:\users\yajat\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\gevent\server.py", line 192, in get_listener
return _tcp_listener(address, backlog=backlog, reuse_addr=cls.reuse_addr, family=family)
File "c:\users\yajat\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\gevent\server.py", line 288, in _tcp_listener
sock.bind(address)
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted: ('', 8089)
[2020-10-28 12:53:30,241] DESKTOP-YAJAT/INFO/locust.main: Running teardowns...
[2020-10-28 12:53:30,241] DESKTOP-YAJAT/INFO/locust.main: Shutting down (exit code 2), bye.
[2020-10-28 12:53:30,242] DESKTOP-YAJAT/INFO/locust.main: Cleaning up runner...
Name                                                          # reqs      # fails  |     Avg     Min     Max  Median  |   req/s failures/s

---

Aggregated                                                         0     0(0.00%)  |       0       0       0       0  |    0.00    0.00

Response time percentiles (approximated)
Type     Name                                                              50%    66%    75%    80%    90%    95%    98%    99%  99.9% 99.99%   100% # reqs
--------|------------------------------------------------------------|---------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
--------|------------------------------------------------------------|---------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|

pls help
os - windows 10 pro
python version - 3.8
locust version - latest i reinstalled it

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might have more than one thing running on port 8089. Possibly you have multiple Locust instances running.
[(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. Windows apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51828763/os-10048only-one-usage-of-each-socket-address-protocol-network-address-port)

Comment: It wouldn't be your code. It would be how you're running it. Maybe you have Locust running from your IDE and then you're also trying to run it via a shell? The port 8089 (which is the default port Locust uses) is already in use somewhere when you try to run it. You can change the port it uses by adding `--web-port 8090` to your run command.

Answer (score 0):

ok it worked i was using python 3.9 so it was glitching i switched to 3.6 worked fine without changing the web port any way thanks